# Android - How to make this parallax animation (see the animation)

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I've a big doubt, how can I make this animation (see it below) in the Android? [image: see the gif]

> What I've tried before?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!--THIS TOOLBAR NEEDS TO BE FIXED ON THE TOP-->
    <!--TO DONT TO BE SCROLLED-->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_fixed_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>


            <!--CONTENT OF HEADER BELOW OF TOOLBAR-->
            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Contacts"/>
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="12"/>
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Amount"/>
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="675.353,45"/>
                <!--CONTENT OF WHITE VIEW HERE-->

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!--CONTENT OF WHITE VIEW HERE-->

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But the layout breaks, because the second **Toolbar**, appears with a large text, and it gets over my **Header** at the moment it's scrolled, and even then, when I do the scroll effect on the page, it looks like I've been placed all within a **ScrollView** and not with an effect and **delay** as it appears in the image above.

> NOTE: The scroll **does not have** the effect of "locking" the button
>   as it is in a time of the image shown, is that I re-animated the
>   animation to show and I'm not that good, so the scroll happens
>   naturally, but with **delay** in this piece that "lock"